# Access all the access tokens from tokenCache in MSAL for Java

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-msal

I have a web application which uses MSAL for Java for Microsoft identity login. My application needs access to two resources.

1. Graph API.
2. Teams API for calling some undocumented Teams API.
   (These APIs are not yet available in graph)

My web app uses AccessCode flow to get the authentication token. Brief below.

1. Use the Teams scope 48ac35b8-9aa8-4d74-927d-1f4a14a0b239/.default to get user login and consent to my app.
2. Now I have the access token. And I can call the Teams API.
3. Use this token and get the graph token by calling the silent flow with scope https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
4. Now I have access token for graph. I can call the graph APIs without issue.
5. I see that the Token Cache now has two access token objects (I serialized the token cache to JSON)
6. However, from the AuthenticationResult object I can only access the second accessToken only as there is no way to get the array.
7. Thus, if my application has to call both graph and Teams API to show the result on the screen, I have to call the silent flow twice by changing the scope.
8. Other way is the manually get the access token from tokenCache.

Is there a better method to what I am doing?

Comment: Hi kaushik , Do you want to use both the token at time ?

Comment: Yes, I will call some Graph APIs and some teams API and show the result on the same page.

I can get the tokenCache instead and iterate and filter the right accessToken but want to avoid that.

Comment: Could you please try using [AcquireTokenSilentAsync][1] to get an access token silently.


  [1]: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token

Comment: Yes I am using the same i.e. AcquireTokenSilent and I am getting the tokens too.

Comment: Ok , then what issue you faced in this case ?

Comment: The object of the Interface IAuthenticationResult through its accessToken method gives access to only the last access token. It would have been great if this function would take the scope/applicationid/resource etc and return the token for that resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about Custom token cache serialization [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-java-token-cache-serialization).

Being said that, please go ahead and submit Github feedback [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%221610a182-c143-09a9-0ede-2e751353c019%22&in=body) for your specific feature ask.

Thanks.